# Issue with SonarQube showing ChromeHeadless error

Tags: angular, sonarqube, ionic3, code-coverage, google-chrome-headless

When executing command "npm run test-coverage", getting below errors.

TOTAL: 373 FAILED, 514 SUCCESS
12 12 2023 15:18:35.549:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sales@0.0.1 test-coverage: `karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --coverage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sales@0.0.1 test-coverage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Username/.npm/_logs/2023-12-12T09_48_35_630Z-debug.log

I tried with running command "npm run test-coverage" and It should show success message.